# Users who are not collabolators can push

Tags: git, github

I am new to git.
Even if a collaborator (my other account) who has not been added to the repository pushes, it will be reflected.
My repositories are private.

Does changing user.name and user.email work regardless of permissions?

What should I set to prevent this? The remote address is currently connected via https method.

Any help please?

Haven't tried anything yet. I'm not sure if I can change it to SSH, what has to do with tokens, or whether these have to do with permissions.

Answer (score 1):

> Does changing user.name and user.email work regardless of permissions?

Yes, it is related to commit authorship, and Git itself does not enforce any permission.

GitHub, on the other end, as a remote Git repositories hosting service, can enforce rules and offer services, like [commit signature verification](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification)

> Repository administrators can enforce required commit signing on a branch to block all commits that are not signed and verified. For more information, see "[About protected branches.](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches#require-signed-commits)"